# Display percentage values in Excel using POI API

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to display a value in an excel cell formatted like a percentage, e.g. like `12.3%`.

By default the value is displayed as Text, but I need to display it as a number.

What is the appropriate method to achieve this?

Comment: @ax, this is a POI question, so it is a question of how to get POI to set the cell type as a percentage.

Answer (score 84):

You need to:

1. Set your data as number (floating-point), not as text.
2. Specify cell format as percentage.

Something like:

```
cell.setCellValue(0.123); // set value as number
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.000%"));
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Take a look at [user defined formats section](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats) of POI quick guide for more details. You may also want to go through the [examples](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) which show how to use different POI capabilities.

Comment: The end result in the excel is not displaying the %, it just displays 0.123 as a value.

Comment: @KayKay Have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: @VladimirApolaiko Nope

Comment: For me it's working perfectly and the type of the cell is Percentage and also with the '%' at the end

Comment: I set the style at the column level with sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

POI has built-in formats check this [link](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html) first

and check this [link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BuiltinFormats) for example

For percentage, it will be something like this

```
dataCell.setCellValue(.12)
CellStyle stylePercentage = workbook.createCellStyle();
stylePercentage.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat()
.getFormat(BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat( 10 )));
 dataCell.setCellStyle(stylePercentage);
```